# Prometheus : how to use relabel to merge metrics and set new time

Tags: date, prometheus

I have the following metrics (from filestat_exporter)

```
{backup_object="website", instance="server1", job="file_exporter", path="/backups/website/04-29-2023.tar.gz"} 5373952
{backup_object="website", instance="server1", job="file_exporter", path="/backups/website/05-01-2023.tar.gz"} 674667398
{backup_object="website", instance="server1", job="file_exporter", path="/backups/website/05-02-2023.tar.gz"} 674707321
{backup_object="website", instance="server1", job="file_exporter", path="/backups/website/05-03-2023.tar.gz"} 674707321
{backup_object="website", instance="server1", job="file_exporter", path="/backups/website/05-04-2023.tar.gz"} 674712580
```

The unique key is backup_object, this is how I differentiate backups and I should have one backup per day.

The scrape interval is 10m, so I have a value every 10m for one file. But this is always the same because my backup file is created once and for all. This is not optimal at this point.

I want to know when a filesize is anormaly low or high compared to the others days.

I think the easiest way to do that is to "assemble" the multiple metrics I have into one that I could query with the `backup_object` label.

So from the example above, I would like to use `relabel` to transform the metrics from filestat_exporter to something like :

```
{backup_object="website", instance="server1", job="file_exporter"} 674712580
```

Taking these values :

```
04-29-2023 -> 5373952
05-01-2023 -> 674667398
05-02-2023 -> 674707321
05-03-2023 -> 674707321
05-04-2023 -> 674712580
```

Even if the value is scraped every 10m and is the same for the whole day, having only one metrics for one `backup_objects` looks way simpler to create alerts and graphs.

The logic I was trying to do was the following :

- use relabel to store the date in a separate label (I managed to do that)
- use relabel to compare the day today with the day in the new `date` label and ignore everything that is not today (=> that I didn't managed to do)
- use relabel to remove the "path" (I did not reach this step, but I should be able to)

How to do the step2 : compare my `date` label with today and ignore (remove ?) every metric that is not today. I've seen this post : [Prometheus grab series where label matches today's date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63544860/prometheus-grab-series-where-label-matches-todays-date) but I wasn't able to adapt the solution to my own use case.

Thanks

Comment: Thinking through comments.... Including measurements of time in label values feels (!?) like an anti-pattern (to be discouraged). Prometheus is essentially a time-series databases and, when it scrapes measurements from exporters, it records the value as a combination of its timestamp of the scrape and your label values. It would be better if you could use its scrape timestamp as your measurement of time too

Comment: Your measurement is a backup job (defined by the backup's filename) and the value is the archive size. Prometheus would then have historical values (each scrape with a timestamp) for these archives and you could use PromQL [`rate`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#rate) and [`<aggregate>_over_time`](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/functions/#rate) functions to monitor trends and find anomalies

Comment: Prometheus stores unique time-series for each combination of a metric (e.g. `filestat_exporter`) and every unique combination of its labels values. For this reason, you should try to keep the set of possible values somewhat (TBD) constrained and preferably limited rather than unbounded. Corollary: `path` adds a time series for each new values (every day, every archive).

Comment: Prometheus is an excellent tool but it is not ideally suited to data analysis. For that you may want to complement Prometheus with a tool like [Grafana](https://grafana.com/)

Comment: In summary of my "rambling"... Consider (1) one metric (name and set of label values) for each unique backup set... e.g. `website` should be a single time-series `my_backups{backup_objet="website",instance="...",job="..."} [value]`; (2) use PromQL functions to perform basic analysis; (3) consider Grafana or other tools for more complex analyses.

Comment: Do you have five versions of backup? And do you need them all stored in Prometheus? And, as correctly stated DazWilkin, are you sure that you need dates there at all (maybe timestamps of metric would suffice)?

Comment: If you have a single backup (and a single metric) every day, and all you need is alert you can skip relabeling and use query that will compare current value with average  over last 4 days. It would look something like `sum by (backup_objext) (my_backups) > 1.1 * (sum by (backup_objext) (my_backups offset 1d) + sum by (backup_objext) (my_backups offset 2d) + sum by (backup_objext) (my_backups offset 3d) +sum by (backup_objext) (my_backups offset 4d) )/4`